# How would you say "grass" as in "Green grass covers his grave."?

Tags: vocabulary, semantics

I am trying to translate some lyrics of a patriotic Croatian song in Latin. Here is what I've got thus far:

> Non sunt heroes,
> non sunt Croati,
> ita fortes ut Jelačić erat.
> Sed nunc eum atra terra tegit,
> et virid...

For "*And green grass covers his grave.*", which word should I use for "*grass*"? Wiktionary claims Latin had two words for "*grass*", "*herba*" and "*gramen*". So, which one should I use? And should I use it in singular or plural? Should I say "*Et viridis herba tegit eius sepulchrum.*" or "*Et virides herbae tegunt eius sepulchrum.*" or "*Et viride gramen tegit eius sepulchrum.*" or "*Et viridia gramina tegunt eius sepulchrum.*"? Or maybe something else?

Comment: I like the 3rd translation. "Et viride gramen tegit eum sepulcrum"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [*herba*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dherba) can mean grass, it can also mean any other small, green plant. Grass is a small, green plant, so it can be an *herba*, but properly it's [*gramen*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgramen).

This is clear in phrases like *herba graminis* (Verg. Ec. 5.26), which means "blade of grass."

The singular is fine. It can sometimes be plural in poetry or when it's referring to a variety of plants. Like how in English "grass" started being used as a slang word for a particular green plant, you also find *gramen* being used for some plants that aren't grass, but that's a secondary development.